# enum class ambiguous overload for 'operator=='

Tags: c++

```cpp
enum class A 
  { W };
bool operator==( const A &a, const A &b )
  { return true; }

int main()
{
  ( A::W == A::W );
}
```

> error: ambiguous overload for 'operator==' (operand types are 'A' and 'A')
>
> note: candidate: operator==(A, A) built-in
>
> note: candidate: bool operator==(const A&, const A&)

Comment: Your compiler is reporting the problem.   enum types implicitly have an `operator==()` that allows comparing two values of that type.   Your `operator==()` has a signature consistent with that but not quite the same, so the compiler sees two overloads versions of `operator==()` and has no reason to prefer one over the other.   Either remove your overload of `operator==()`, or changes its arguments to be passed by value (which will suppress the implicitly generated one).

Comment: It is perhaps worth noting that passing primitives by const reference is a pessimization.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix your issue with

```
bool operator==(A, A) { return true; }
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MnsvT6nM7)